# Urban fantasy, a fallen angel is reborn as a hunchback dwarf

Tags: story-identification

I read this book maybe ten years ago, a hardback from a used book shop uk. I can't recall anything about the cover. I did get the impression that the book was set in the late 1980s but I'm not sure.

There's an angel who messes up somehow (I really can't remember what he did) and thus he gets a bit of Divine punishment.
He's born and grows up in the UK as a hunchback dwarf and works in Brighton.
I think but not sure that he's a private detective. I can't remember much of the story after that.

One scene that I do remember is he's walking along the beach early evening and a few teenagers sitting around a fire mug him, they take his money and beat him up. He walks away crying - not just from the beating up but from shame because they were a bunch of schoolgirls

Comment: Pretty sure it's you, but mentioning the crosspost at http://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/581768/.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yeah, that was me a few months ago, I meant to add that link in my question but forgot!

Comment: I got a bit confused with the Bobby Dollar stories, that's why I was convinced the MC was an angel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Let me try for once:**

*[Others](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/459869.Others)* by James Herbert. MC is a private eye, hunchback and with other crippled features, and I recall a scene where he takes a beating like that.

Unless my memory is totally wrong.

Comment: Takes place in Brighton, check.  Beatdown by teenage girls by the beach, check.  Reincarnation though, not an angel, but otherwise a very good match.  Nice work.